# Telebot taskkill

Tags: python, operating-system

I have a telegram bot written using telebot(pytelegrambotapi) and it has a line of code that closes the programs `os.system('taskkill /F /IM test.exe /T')` but after that the console is displayed `[the process exited with code 1]` and the bot is not responding to my messages.

Comment: Is it possible this line is terminating your bot?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code kills process of your bot. If your problem in that -remove this line, if you want to stop the script - replace this line to `exit()`